# 42703 Error on POSTGRESQL when attempting to insert using KnexJS

Tags: javascript, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

I have been using KnexJS as a framework for maintaining my databases, in development KnexJS uses SQLite3 which gives me no problems, but is set to POSTGRESQL for production (Heroku) which seems to be a lot stricter with how I do things.

When I check Heroku logs, the error I get is this:

```
name: 'error',
length: 121,
severity: 'ERROR',
error: insert into "users" ("city", "country", "email", "fName", "lName", 
"organisation", "password", "phone", "street_address", "suburb", 
"user_image_url") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) - 
column "city" of relation "users" does not exist
code: '42703'
```

This is what my seeds look like:

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('users').del()
    .then(function () {
  // Inserts seed entries
  return knex('users').insert([
    {fName: 'Person', lName: 'One', organisation: 'Company', email: 'person1@place.com', street_address: '70 King St', suburb: 'Kelburn', city:'Auckland', country: 'New Zealand', phone: 027027027, 'user_image_url': '', password: ''},
    {fName: 'Person', lName: 'Two', organisation: 'Catch22', email: 'person2@place.com', street_address: '70 Prince St', suburb: 'Ngunguru', city:'Wellington', country: 'New Zealand',  phone: 021021021, 'user_image_url': '', password: ''}
  ]);
});
};
```

This is my migration for users.

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', function (table) {
    table.increments('id')
    table.string('fName')
    table.string('lName')
    table.integer('phone')
    table.string('password')
    table.string('email')
    table.string('street_address')
    table.string('suburb')
    table.string('organisation')
    table.string('user_image_url')
    table.string('city')
    table.string('country')
})
};

 exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users')
};
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: delete all the table on server manually and then run migrate.

Comment: check your DB schema by hand and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö I have checked my schema but I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: Try to take a look at `\d users` from your `postgres` console and find your column there. Also, did you edit your migration file? `knex` runs migration file just once for database (so as any other mature migration tool) and stores applied migrations in separate table, so your future edits to database should be in separate migrations. Maybe this is the case.